# Silverlight - Closing a Service

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I'm working on a Silverlight application that works with WCF services. While loading the service metadata in my browser, I noticed that it provides the following code:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        myServiceClient client = new myServiceClient();

        // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

        // Always close the client.
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

The last line says "Always close the client". My question is, when should you close the client in a Silverlight application? Should you close it after your call to "[MyServiceOperation]Async" or should you close it in the "[MyServiceOperation]Completed" event handler?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Close` blocks when used in an asynchronous scenario.

There is also a `BeginClose`/`EndClose` asynchronous variant of the code if you do not want your calling code to block, but from what I can see if you call `.Close` it will wait until your outstanding calls resolve before `.Close` returns.

Also note that calling it in your Completed handler may cause issues with multiple async calls to the same client object... I would recommend doing it in the calling code either with `.Close` or `.BeginClose`

Updated: [From the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195520%28VS.95%29.aspx) (although somewhat buried)

> This method causes an
>   ICommunicationObject  to gracefully
>   transition from the Opened  state to
>   the Closed  state. The Close  method
>   allows any unfinished work to be
>   completed before returning. (For
>   example, finish sending any buffered
>   messages.)

...

> Close  returns after the Closed  state is reached.